# How do I prevent unauthorized users from even pulling up a page on firebase portal?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, security, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to make a "secure" portal using vanilla JavaScript and HTML on firebase, but I am running into an issue where I am able to pull up a portal page without being logged in.

I have the app configured to authenticate using Google Workspace accounts (according to [this page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin)) and I am currently able to check if a user is logged in (using the Firebase 9 function onAuthStateChanged as defined [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)).

It currently redirects fairly quickly to the login page, but my concern is that for a millisecond the page pulls up. I fixed this by adding the hidden attribute to the appropriate sections, but it is still up on the HTML and could be scraped.

What is the best way of getting around this issue? My gut tells me that I just need to make the rest of the app appear dynamically using JavaScript and just keep the HTML limited to basically a function call, but I want to rule out other options because I have no idea how to do that yet.

I have looked for vanilla JavaScript solutions, but have mostly found answers that use PHP (and the stack overflow answers I have found seemed unsure).